# What is the difference of () and = in creating class instances?

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor, copy-constructor

I try to create 2 objects of a class like this

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

class MyNum
{
private: 
    int m_num;
public:
    MyNum(int num) : m_num{ num }
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyNum one(1);
    MyNum two = 2;
}
```

What is the difference between these two lines

```
MyNum one(1);
MyNum two = 2;
```

Comment: The first one is called [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) while the other is [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization). There are subtle differences between them. In your case they will do the same thing.

Comment: You might need a book. Look at beginner's list of this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/4123703

Comment: Also this works since `MyNum(int num)` qualifies as [converting constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor) because it takes only one parameter andis not marked `explicit`.

Answer (score 4):

`MyNum one(1)` performs [direct initalization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization), `MyNum two = 2;` performs [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization). They have the same effect here, i.e. initializing the object by the constructor `MyNum::MyNum(int)`.

If you mark the constructor as `explicit` then the 2nd one becomes ill-formed.

> Copy-initialization is less permissive than direct-initialization: explicit constructors are not converting constructors and are not considered for copy-initialization.